# Proof: $2n! < 2^{2n} (n!)^{2}$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Could someone help with finishing this inequality induction proof.

Hypothesis: $2n! < 2^{2n}(n!)^2$

Step: $2(n+1)! < 2^{2(n+1)}((n+1)!)^2$

(2n+2)! < 2ˆ(2n + 1) * ((n + 1)!)ˆ2

Comment: do you mean $$(2n)!<2^{2n}(n!)^2$$?

Comment: Sorry but where is your beginning of an induction proof?

Answer (score 1):

You want

$$
2(n+1)! = (n+1) 2n! < 2^{2(n+1)}((n+1)!)^2
$$

By induction hypothesis, use $2n! < 2^{2n}(n!)^2$ so you need to establish

$$
(n+1) 2^{2n}(n!)^2 < 2^{2(n+1)}((n+1)!)^2
$$
or

$$
(n+1) (n!)^2 < 2((n+1)!)^2 = 2 (n+1)^2(n!)^2
$$
or
$$
1 <  2 (n+1)
$$
which is clearly true.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $4n^2+6n+2 < 4n^2+8n+4$ so $\color{blue}{2(n+1)(2n+1)< 2^2(n+1)^2}$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
(2(n+1))!=2(n+1)(2n+1) \underbrace{\color{red}{(2n)!} < \color{blue}{2(n+1)}}_{ \text{by the } {\color{red}{ \text{inductive hypothesis}}}}\color{blue}{(2n+1)} \color{red}{2^{2n}}\underbrace { \color{red}{(n!)^2} < \color{blue}{2^2(n+1)^2}}_{ \text{using the above}} 2^{2n} (n!)^2=2^{2(n+1)} ((n+1)!)^2.
\end{eqnarray*}